# Is double voting allowed?

Tags: discussion, voting

This morning I looked at an answer that I had up-voted last year, and realized that I had originally misread part of it.  It really shouldn't have had my up-vote, so I clicked on the up-triangle, and instead of removing my vote, it added another point to the score.

Rather than correcting my mistake, I *doubled* it.
And to make it worse, my two votes are the *only* votes on this answer.

Are we really allowed to vote more than once?

And if this *isn't* a bug, how should I have removed my vote?

Comment: I've never seen such a thing happen, and I doubt it did to you. Maybe there was some network lag so it looked like more votes happened than really did. You can see on their profile how their reputation changed today.

Comment: I've seen it happen where I remove an upvote, but the post score increments by 1. When I refresh the page, the score reflects correctly and my upvote is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have been pretty unheard of; the system won't let you vote twice on a post with the same account. Was the upvote arrow already blue when you visited the page? Perhaps you realized, say, 6 months ago that your upvote wasn't warranted and did you retract it then already. The post's score might still be 1 because another user upvoted it.

In any case, you can visit your profile and check [the upvotes you've given](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote) (other users, including moderators, can't see them); since there are only 48 (that number *is* public), you should be able to figure out quickly whether you voted for that answer in the past.

Comment: The vote arrow was already blue.  My original downvote was 31 December 2018, with no other record of it in my votes.  So perhaps I was hallucinating, but I was sure I saw the counter change from 1 to 2.  (Or, very unlikely, someone else happened to upvote it at the same time.)  Thanks, and sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: "3961", with ten times my reputation, reports having experienced the same thing.  So perhaps I'm not as delusional as I thought (and I guess I must have seen it go from 2 to 3, and assumed the reverted-to 2 was the result I saw).

Answer (score 1):

**Is double voting allowed?**

The real answer is **no**! And I truly doubt that the event you described actually happened.

You can always edit the response you updated and then you will be able to remove your vote, if you truly feel the response does not merit being upvoted by yourself.